# Why does Typescript throw an error if the code that throws an error in my catch block is surrounded by an if statement?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to throw an error if the error status code is anything but 401, however, as soon as I enclosed the line of code that throws the error, my typescript started giving me the following error:

```
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
```

My function looks like this:

```
export const addToDo = async (title: string, color: string): Promise<number> => {
    try {
        const { body: toDoId } = await request.post('/todo').send({ title, color });

        return toDoId;
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.status !== 401) {
            throw new Error('error');
        }
    }
};
```

Once I remove the if statement in the catch block, I stop getting this error.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory.  What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm kinda new to Typescript so my question is how to avoid getting that error. I guess it's because my catch block potentially doesn't return anything, but how would I change my function so that I allow my catch block to return nothing if the status code is 401?

Comment: It is complaining that you don’t handle the error in anyway if the status is not 401

Comment: @kellys I don't want to handle the error if it is 401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To annotate your function a bit:

```
export const addAccountGoal = async (title: string, color: string): Promise<number> => {
    try {
        const { body: goalId } = await request.post('/goals/account/addGoal').send({ title, color });
        await setActiveGoal(goalId);
        return goalId;
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.status !== 401) {
            throw new Error('GENERIC_ERROR');
        } else {
            // WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE
        }
    }
};
```

Your problem is that you haven't told TypeScript anything for "what should I do here", so execution continues to the end of the function, where you don't return anything. Hence the error message, "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'."

Depending on the specific logic you want:

- You could explicitly `return undefined;` and change the function's return type to `Promise<number | undefined>`.
- You could re-throw the error (`throw e;`).
- You could return a default value (`return 0;`).
- Something completely different

(The `else {` that I added is just for explanatory purposes; you don't have to write your code that way unless you want to.)